# Is the ASIHTTPRequest is not asynchronous?

Tags: iphone, asynchronous, request, asihttprequest

I am using ASIHTTPRequest to fetch some data from a web service.

I am making requests using a loop.

The problem is that it doesn't seem the request is going asynchronously so that my activityindicator is not working .

Is it true that ASIHTTPRequest is not asynchronous .

or should i use the regular nsmutablerequest to perform asynchronous request .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put your request in a download queue, i.e.

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestWentWrong:)];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[queue addOperation:request];
[request release];
```

Just

```
[request startAsynchronous];
```

runs the request on the UI thread, so you should try it with download queue.

Comment: the nsoperation line is giving error saying that the sharedAppDelegate method will not respond to the MyAppDelegate. and the line [request startAsynnchronous] is also giving the same warning .

Comment: yap, because is just an example.. wait a minute

Comment: edited the answer. [request startAsynchronous] doesn't belong to the first code snippet.

Comment: ok so basically i am given the mehthod [request start]; is it ok .

Comment: startAsynchronous cannot be found in the class header, and it gives a warning.
The operation queue is something I banged my head on the wall for a long time until I thought of it.

Comment: seems that startAsynchronous isn't longer supported. Strange, the documentation still mention it.

Comment: startAsynchronous is absolutely still supported - I'm surprised it isn't showing up in the header for you. The behaviour has changed in the latest version (1.5 as time of writing) - requests started with startAsynchronous now run in thread they were started from, rather than in a global operation queue.

startAsynchronous won't update the network activity indicator for you, though it should be trivial to do that yourself. Or, use a queue, as Henrik recommended :)

Answer (score 0):

**For Sync Synchronous**

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
  ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
  [request startSynchronous];
  NSError *error = [request error];
  if (!error) {
    NSString *response = [request responseString];
  }
```

**Creating an asynchronous request**

```
- (IBAction)grabURLInBackground:(id)sender
{
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
   ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setDelegate:self];
   [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   // Use when fetching text data
   NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

   // Use when fetching binary data
   NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   NSError *error = [request error];
}
```

And there is lot of more options like Queue and many more

You can refer http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use